# Shell programing- replace a specific word with another

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I an a beginer in shell programming and I  want to replace with shell the third word for a text with the first word on every line. The words are separed by a ":" . Can you help me? Thx a lot.

Comment: add an example to make this clearer

Comment: if a have the text : "You are the best", I want my  shell programming return "the are the best"

Comment: No, I'm just curios :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with this test file:

```
$ cat file
one:two:three:four:five
up:and:down
1:2:3:4
```

#### Using awk

To replace "the third word for a text with the first word on every line":

```
$ awk -F: '{$3=$1} 1' OFS=: file
one:two:one:four:five
up:and:up
1:2:1:4
```

How it works:

- `-F:` tells awk to use `:` as the field separator on input.
- `$3=$1` tells awk to replace the third word with the first.
- `1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.
- `OFS=:` tells awk to use `:` as the field separator on output.

#### Using shell

```
$ while IFS=: read a b c d ; do echo "$a:$b:$a:$d"; done <file
one:two:one:four:five
up:and:up:
1:2:1:4
```

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -E 's/([^:]*):([^:]*):[^:]*/\1:\2:\1/' file
one:two:one:four:five
up:and:up
1:2:1:4
```

Comment: @TeodoraCiont OK.  I added a `sed` solution.